# Replace column values in an SQL query without updating the original table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am looking for a way to change column values upon select query without modifying the data in the original table

I have a `cities` table

| Id | name | timezone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris | CET |
| 2 | Tokyo | JST |

I also have a `translation` table

| reference_id | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | "name" | パリ |
| 2 | "timezone" | タイムゾーン |

Where `reference_id` is the `id` in the `cities` table, and `field` is the name of column in `cities` table, and `value` is the translated text

I want a query that swap column value with `translation.value where translation.field = cities.column_name`

**without updating cities table **

I'm Expecting result to be somewhat like this

| Id | name | timezone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris | CET |
| 2 | パリ | タイムゾーン |

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer join:

```
select c.id, 
       coalesce(n.value, c.name) as name,
       coalesce(tz.value, c.timezone) as timezone
from cities c
  left join translation n on c.id = n.reference_id and n.field = 'name'
  left join translation tz on c.id = tz.reference_id and tz.field = 'timezone';
```

If you need that a lot, you can put this into a view.

Comment: Is there a way to make n.field dynamic ? I want to compare n.field with column names without specifying it statically

Comment: @AhmedAlTayeh: no, you can't make that dynamic as the number, names and data types of all columns in the SELECT list must be defined _before_ the database starts retrieving data.